# android studio target application

Tags: android-studio, target

I try to use android studio. I created simple app. When I launch it I see that it is  application which I created before not the current which I want to launch. I am really confused how to change target for app.

Comment: is it solved???

Answer (score 0):

You just follow this steps it will helpful

Whenever you want to update your minSdkVersion in current project

- Update src/build.gradle - Make sure is the one under src folder
- Sync gradle button
- Rebuild project